# Testing an actors that creates child actors

Tags: scala, unit-testing, akka

For example, I have two actors - a parent actor and a child actor. When a parent receives a message, it spawns as many child actors as specified in the message. How can I test this functionality? Is there a way to mock the context or some other way to check that the actors are created correctly and in the right amount?

```
class ParentActor extends Actor {
  case class CreateChildren(count: Int)

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case CreateChildren(count) => for (_ <- 0 until count) context.actorOf(Props[ChildActor])
  }
}

class ChildActor extends Actor {
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case _ =>
  }
}
```

**Updated:** Solution based on @Tim answer

Changed classes:

```
class ParentActor(childActorFactory: ChildActorFactory) extends Actor {
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case CreateChildren(count) => for (_ <- 0 until count) childActorFactory.create(context)
  }
}

object ParentActor {
  def props(childActorFactory: ChildActorFactory): Props = Props(new ParentActor(childActorFactory))
}

class ChildActorFactory {
  def create(context: ActorContext): ActorRef = context.actorOf(Props[ChildActor])
}
```

Test:

```
"ParentActor" should {
    "instantiate ten child actors" in {
      val childrenCount = 10
      val childActorFactory = mock[ChildActorFactory]
      val parentActor = TestActorRef[ParentActor](ParentActor.props(childActorFactory))

      parentActor ! CreateChildren(childrenCount)

      Mockito.verify(childActorFactory, Mockito.times(childrenCount))
        .create(parentActor.underlyingActor.context)
    }
  }
```

Comment: Why do you want to create so many actors? Don't you want to do `context.become` to one of them? Are you sure you just want to create them?

Comment: @TomerShetah Separate actors run asynchronously, allowing greater parallelism, whereas using `context.become` is serial. This also allows state to be localised in child actors rather than centralised in the parent.

Comment: @Tim, as far as I know, until you add them to context, they are not call at all. far example  if you add in the `ChildActor` receive function: `case s => println(s)`, and send a string to `ParentActor`, it won't be resolved.

Comment: @TomerShetah This is pseudo-code provided to support a specific question about actor creation and testing, so don't read too much into the fact that the code is incomplete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to mock the child actor if you want to fully test the Parent actor, so you can't create the child actor directly in the parent actor. Instead, pass a factory method to the parent actor (dependency injection):

```
class ParentActor(makeChild: () => ChildActor) extends Actor {
  case class CreateChildren(count: Int)

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case CreateChildren(count) => for (_ <- 0 until count) makeChild() 
  }
}
```

The `makeChild` function can count the number of actors that are created. It can also return a mock version of `ChildActor` that implements test behaviour to stress the `ParentActor`.

Comment: Thank you! I expanded my code based on your answer and everything works just fine.